# How to create mutiple connection profiles and multiple nodes in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have a scenario where I have to create multiple nodes with same or various organisations.
As per my understanding changes required in below files while setting up the blockchain network Hyperledger Composer Version 1.0
- createComposerProfile.sh
- docker-compose.yml

Can you please tell me whether my understanding is correct or not. Also please guide me the changes required in those files.

Answer (score 0):

Our development server is a simple setup of Hyperledger Fabric and is not really provided as an example of how to create a Hyperledger Fabric, it is there purely to provide a real Hyperledger Fabric for testing purposes for Hyperledger Composer applications. If you want to learn more about creating and building your own Hyperledger Fabric environment then documentation provided by the Hyperledger Fabric team is the place to go. You could try starting at
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html
which provides information on how to build your first network